# I have a JS function that should change the innerHTML of a td based off of an event change in a DropDownListFor, but only works on initial load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a JS function that should be changing the innerHTML of a TD based off of the value of a DropDownListFor. It works on the intial load, but does not work when the drop down list is changed again. I also have second function that should be calling the first function when the drop down list is changed... Here is my code.

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y:scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Terminal</th>
                    <th>Command</th>
                    <th>Command Value</th>
                    <th> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalsDDL, Model.TerminalsDDL, new { id = "ddlTerminalID", @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL, Model.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL, new {id = "ddlCommandValue", @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.UserEnteredTerminalCommands, new { Class = "form-control", Id = "cmdValueValue"})</td>
                    <td> <input id="btnSaveTerminalCommand" type="button"  value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" id="helpDescript" onchange="UpdateHelpDescript();">@*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HelpDescription)*@</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS functions:

```
 function GetHelpDescriptionFromddlCommandValue() {

    var hd = document.getElementById("helpDescript");
    //var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var cmdID = document.getElementById("ddlCommandValue");

    var cmd = cmdID.options[cmdID.selectedIndex].text;

    if (cmd == "UpdateConfig") {
        var helpDescript = "No current help description.";
    }
    if (cmd == "PushLogsToS3") {
        var helpDescript = "No current help description.";
    }
    if (cmd == "PushRecentLogsToS3") {
        var helpDescript = "Command Value is the number of days you wish to retreive.";
    }
    if (cmd == "UnlockCard") {
        var helpDescript = "No current help description.";
    }
    if (cmd == "GetWorkingKey") {
        var helpDescript = "No current help description.";
    }
    if (cmd == "GetNewBuild") {
        var helpDescript = "Pre-Approved S3 URL";
    }
    if (cmd == "ExitApp") {
        var helpDescript = "No current help description."
    }

    return helpDescript;
}

document.getElementById("helpDescript").innerHTML = GetHelpDescriptionFromddlCommandValue();

function UpdateHelpDescript() {
    document.getElementById("helpDescript").innerHTML = GetHelpDescriptionFromddlCommandValue();

}
```

Can someone please explain why the second function is not working on the change? Thank you!

Comment: You are setting your onchange event on a <td> element. This should be placed on your select element or whatever you are using for your "drow down list". An onchange for a non form element isnt going to just fire for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put OnChange Event in drop-down element.
2. Use unobtrusive Js (Seperate js from html).
   for ex:

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#helpDescript").html(GetHelpDescriptionFromddlCommandValue());
   });